# $p_{i + k} - p_i \neq \text{const}$ for any $k \geq 1$ where $p_i = i$th prime number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, integers, prime-gaps

Let $p_i$ be the $i$th prime number.  This should be simple to prove:

$$
\forall k \geq 1, c \in \Bbb{Z}, \\
p_{i + k} - p_i \neq c, \\
$$
for some $i \geq 2$.  But for example:

$$
11 - 5 = 6 \\
13 - 7 = 6 \\
17 - 11 = 6 \\
19 - 13 = 6 \\
23 - 17 = 6 \\
$$

So long strips do exist, I'm saying the whole diagonal strip (a diagonal line in the table for $p_i - p_j$) cannot be constant.

I specified $i \geq 2$ because I'm only interested in odd primes, but lowering to $i \geq 1$ should also work.

It should be easy to prove, but I'm stuck on it.

---

If $p_{i + k} - p_i = c$ for all $i \geq 2$ then in particular $3 + cz$ is prime for all $z \geq 0$, which would include $z \in 3 \Bbb{Z}$?  Does that work as a proof?

My next question is how can we generalize the statement? I got a little too specific with the indices.

---

I think I've got it now.

Let $b,c,k \in \Bbb{N}$ be positive numbers.  Then:

$$
p_b + c = p_{b + k} \\
p_{b + k} + c = p_{b + 2k} \\
p_{b + 2k} + c = p_{b + 3k} \\
\vdots
$$

would imply
$$
p_b + c = p_{b + k} \\
p_b + 2c = p_{b + 2k} \\
p_b + 3c = p_{b + 3k} \\
\vdots
$$
or in general $p_b + cz = p_{b + zk}$ for all $z \geq 0$.  Thus choose any $z \in p_{b}\Bbb{N}$.  For more tightness we'd only have to choose the minimal composite in $w \in p_b + c \Bbb{N}$, and then take $z = \dfrac{w - p_b}{c}$

Thus to generalize, $b + zk$ was in the place of $i + k$ so:

$$
b + zk = i + k = b + \dfrac{w - p_b}{c} k \implies \\
\exists i, b \leq i \leq b + k(\dfrac{w - p_b}{c} - 1) : \\
p_{i + k} - p_i \neq c \\
$$

Comment: Not exactly proof but you could use the Prime Number Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question,
the fact that there there are,
for any $n$,
more than $n$ consecutive
composite integers
should prove what you want
by taking $n > c$.

Comment: Could you expound on this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard argument that any non-constant polynomial $g(n) \in \mathbb Z[n]$ takes (arbitrarily large) composite values.  Your problem is just the case of a polynomial of degree $1$.

Pick any value of $g(n_0)$ that you like (pick $n_0$ large enough so that $|g(n_0)|>1$).  If it's composite, then great.  If it's a prime $p$, then note that $g(n_0 + kp) \equiv g(n_0) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ for any $k\ge 1$.  Now it's possible that $g(n_0 + kp)$ is exactly equal to $\pm p$ and hence still prime, but this can only happen for finitely many values of $k$.  Thus $g(n_0 + kp)$ will eventually be always composite for large enough $k$.